# file NULL not being forgotten by loop - C

Tags: c, loops, while-loop

I'm trying to check a directory for a file. I've done that properly. But I'm having trouble for exceptions--> when the file is not there. Here's what I am wanting to do: I 'd like to check for the file, if it exists, then exit the loop. If the file does not exist, then sleep. After sleeping for 3 seconds, check for the file again. Repeat until the file is found then return to main() and print "Hello everyone".

Currently, if the file is missing and i put the file into this directory while the program is running, it never recognizes the new file until i stop the program then start it back up. I want the program to check for the file again after sleep.

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define MYFILE "/Users/stackoverflow/Documents/fileabc123"

int checkfile() {
    FILE *pFile;
    pFile = fopen(MYFILE,"r");
    char file_string[40];
    int repeat = 0;

    while( repeat < 1) {
        if (pFile!=NULL) {
            fgets (file_string,36,pFile);
            fclose (pFile);
            printf("%s\n", file_string);
            repeat = 1 ;
        }

        if (pFile ==NULL) {
            printf("Machine cannot read system file. \n");
            sleep(3);
        }
    }
}


int main (int argc, char ** argv) {
    checkfile();
    printf("Hello everyone\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Move the 'fopen' call to the loop body.

Comment: I must ask, did you even read your code?  The `fopen` is clearly outside of the loop, so it's only going to happen once, and therefore once it fails will always fail. This is just simple debugging, and pretty much useless to future visitors.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it shows no debugging effort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put the `fopen` in the loop.

```
if ((pFile = fopen(MYFILE, "r")) != NULL) {
    // read it
}
else {
    printf("Failed opening");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is in the loop.

you simply aren't trying to open the file again :)

this give you 2 error:
1. if you put the file it is not seen, as the program does not try to open it
2. if the file is present, you read it, then you close it, leaving an INVALID file descriptr but that is NOT null

this mean next loop you will try to read an invalid file descriptor. It is like reading/writing value with a overflow index from an array, or from a free() pointer.
You will almost always have the right value.. until that ram is reallocated.

so:
1. you have to try to open a file, until you get a valid file descriptor.
2. close will not change pointer value. It simply can't, think about it.

if you whant to change the value of somthing, you have to give it's address. A pointer is the adress of somthing. So File* is pointing to a File, but if you want to change the address pointed by File*, you need it's address (&pFile), just like a scanf :)